# How to write Objective-C to Swift 4 below method?

Tags: ios, swift4

Below is Objective-c Code.
I need this method in Swift, how can I write in Swift4?
I'm new to swift, please help.

```
-(NSMutableArray)dataArray
{
    if(!_dataArray)
    {
        _dataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
return _dataArray;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

Comment: Prefer Swift Array rather than NSStuff like `NSArray`, and for that, use a `lazy var`?

Comment: `var dataArry = [Your_Element_Type]()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above method you used in Objective-C is to initialise the memory to `dataArray` when it is being used. It is generally used to minimise memory consumption.

In swift, this process is being handled by lazily instantiated properties, by putting a keyword `lazy` before the property. It will allocate the memory to property only when it is firstly being used.

```
lazy var dataArray = [String]()
```

***Note: In swift, use swift based array rather than `NSArray/ NSMutableArray`***

If you want some customisation to your `dataArray`, you can do it like:

```
lazy var dataArray: [String] = {
        var temp = [String]()
        temp.append("John Doe")
        return temp
        }()
```

You can refer the link: http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/

Comment: got it Well explained.